# Recurrance relation: T (n/16) + n log n

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence, master-theorem

Can the master theorem be applied?

Or say for `T (n) = 2T (n/16) + n log n`, how is the master theorem applied here?

I get `a = 2`, `b = 16` and I am not sure about `c` and `k`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve such a recurrence relation `T(n) = a⋅T(n/b) + f(n)`, you have to calculate `e = logb(a)`.

Then (for an `ε > 0`):

1. `f(n) ∈ O(ne - ε)`  ⇒ `T(n) ∈ Θ(ne)`
2. `f(n) ∈ Θ(ne)`  ⇒ `T(n) ∈ Θ(ne⋅log(n))`
3. `f(n) ∈ Ω(ne + ε)`  ⇒ `T(n) ∈ Θ(f(n))`

For more details see [Masters Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

So in your case: `a = 2`, `b = 16` ⇒ `e = log16(2) = 0.25` holds for case 3,
so `T(n)` is in `Θ(n log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the log (n) term was not there the reduction in work per sub-problem at each level dominates (b > a). Hence in my opinion the complexity shall be dictated by the work done at highest level viz O (nlogn).